# Why I am not able to use index method on NodeList?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

For some reasons, I cannot use index method of NodeList object. When I do typeof on items of headElements I receive it as a object than node.

I want to append every node of headElements and rowElements to tr element.

Here is my code:

```
var pageHeads = document.getElementsByTagName('thead');
var pageBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');


var headElements = pageHeads[i].querySelectorAll('td');
var rowElements = pageBody[i].querySelectorAll('td');

headElements.index(0).cloneNode(true);
```

Comment: `headElements.item(0)`

Comment: @Maxx  headElements.index is not a function; this is what receive for headElements.item(0)

Comment: There is no `index` method in `NodeList`, remove your `headElements.index(0).cloneNode(true);` construction and replace with `headElements.item(0).cloneNode(true);`

Comment: I still not able to use cloneNode(true) on headElements.item(0)

Comment: Can you please specify what you want exactly. Do you want to append the node ?

Comment: What "not able to use cloneNode(true)" means? Errors or what?

Answer (score 1):

The `.index()` method is not a native JavaScript method, but a Jquery method. This is why you get the error `headElements.index is not a function`.

```
var headElements = pageHeads[i].querySelectorAll('td');
var rowElements = pageBody[i].querySelectorAll('td');
```

In addition, these two lines do not make much sense outside of a loop. `i` is simply a variable that stores the index of whatever `pageHeads` elements you which to select. Unless `i` is defined (inside or outside a loop), your code will return an error.

## Solution

(1) Set `i` to the index of the `pageHeads` element you wish to use.

(2) To access a child element of `pageHeads`, simply find out its index. Use the index with bracket notation to access the child element.

```
var headElements = pageHeads[0].querySelectorAll('td');
headElements[0]; // This will return the first element in the headElements nodelist.
```

## Edit

It seems you are looking for the wrong child elements in your table head.

```
var headElements = pageHeads[i].querySelectorAll('td');
```

should be:

```
var headElements = pageHeads[i].querySelectorAll('th');
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5ygeogd/)

Comment: I actually use those lines of codes inside the **for** loop. If I use headElements[0] I cannot seem to clone the element. That is the problem.

Comment: It actually works. I think the problem is because you are looking for ```td``` elements, and not ```th``` elements in your ```thead```. See the fiddle in my edit.

Comment: in my table here, there is td element, not th

Comment: It would be better to use ```th``` elements in your tablehead, and ```td``` elements in your tablebody, but that's another issue. I updated the fiddle with ```td``` elements in the tablehead, like in your code, and it still works. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var pageHeads = document.getElementsByTagName('thead');
var pageBody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody');


var headElements = pageHeads[i].querySelectorAll('td');
var rowElements = pageBody[i].querySelectorAll('td');

headElements.item(0).cloneNode(true);
```

Hope this helps !